# Where are determiners required?

Tags: determiners, zero-article

Please have a look at this sentence:
*I'm French-speaking person.*

Is this correct grammatically?
I would use an indefinite article this way:
*I'm **a** French-speaking person.*

Would you agree please?

Comment: Yes, most count nouns require a determiner, and this is no exception.

Comment: You can just say *Im French*. Of course you speak French

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anytime you add a modifier to the noun, and you're not sure whether to use an article (definite or indefinite), remove the modifier and see what makes sense.

> I'm person.
>
> I'm a person.

Clearly, the second one is correct.

Therefore:

> I'm a French-speaking person.